# How do I expose a GRPC service with Istio on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, istio

Trying to setup grpc service via istio ingress controller

I can access istio http, but not grpc. Service grpc is working.

Ingress is here:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: scrapper
spec:
  ingressClassName: istio
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: scrapper
      port:
        number: 50051
```

Istio class is here:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: istio
spec:
  controller: istio.io/ingress-controllerdu
```

Service is here. Service is working:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: scrapper
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 50051
    name: grpc
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 50051
  selector:
    run: scrapper
  clusterIP: None
```

ingress Host port:

```
export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl -n "$INGRESS_NS" get service "$INGRESS_NAME" -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n "$INGRESS_NS" get service "$INGRESS_NAME" -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].port}')
export SECURE_INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n "$INGRESS_NS" get service "$INGRESS_NAME" -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="https")].port}')
export TCP_INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n "$INGRESS_NS" get service "$INGRESS_NAME" -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="tcp")].port}')



http://10.106.117.71:80/status/200
```

for which host port should I access ingress grpc service?